# How to decimal-align a table using dcolumn package

Tags: dcolumn

I have the following table, and would like to decimal align all the numbers. Can you please suggest how to do it?

```
\newpage
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering 
\begin{changemargin}{0.0cm}{0.5cm}
\caption{Sample title }
\end{changemargin} 

\begin{tabular}{ l  p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} } \hline\hline
 & \textit{Taxation1}  & \textit{Taxation2}  & \textit{Taxation3}
& \textit{Taxation4}   & \textit{Taxation5$^1$}  \\ \hline
\textbf{Marginal Tax Rates} & & & & &  \\ \hline

Labor & 27.37& 26.77& 27.37&26.84 &26.92 \\ 

  &     &(-0.60) & & (-0.53)&(-0.45)\\ 

Dividends & 23.44& 22.92&23.44 & 22.98&23.05 \\ 
 & &(-0.52) & & (-0.46)&(-0.39)\\ 


Interest &28.06 &27.44 &28.06 & 27.51 &27.60\\ 
  & &(-0.62) & & (-0.55)&(-0.46)\\ 


Capital Gains &19.00 &18.58 & 19.00& 18.63 &18.69\\ 
 & &(-0.42) & & (-0.37)&(-0.31)\\ 


Corporate & 46.00 & 46.00& 37.96& 45.10 &46.00\\ 
 & & & (-8.04) &(-0.90) & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\\
\begin{enumerate} [ $^1$ ]
%\item [\text{Note: }]
\item Footnote1
\item Footnote2

\end{enumerate}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! In your example you've not actually got any use of the `dcolumn` package: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to add this before begin document: \usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn} and tried this line in the table \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{D{.}{.}{7}}@{} l  p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} } \hline\hline

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Please always post complete documents not fragments using commands from unspecified packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering 
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{#1}}}

\caption{Tax Rates and Rates Reductions under Alternative Revenue-Recycling Methods }

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ l *{5}{D..{-1} }} \hline\hline
 & \hd{Taxation1}  & \hd{Taxation2}  & \hd{Taxation3}
& \hd{Taxation4}   & \hd {Taxation5$^1$}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Marginal Tax Rates}}\\ \hline
Labor & 27.37& 26.77& 27.37&26.84 &26.92 \\ 
  &     &(-0.60) & & (-0.53)&(-0.45)\\ 
Dividends & 23.44& 22.92&23.44 & 22.98&23.05 \\ 
 & &(-0.52) & & (-0.46)&(-0.39)\\ 
Interest &28.06 &27.44 &28.06 & 27.51 &27.60\\ 
  & &(-0.62) & & (-0.55)&(-0.46)\\ 
Capital Gains &19.00 &18.58 & 19.00& 18.63 &18.69\\ 
 & &(-0.42) & & (-0.37)&(-0.31)\\ 
Corporate & 46.00 & 46.00& 37.96& 45.10 &46.00\\ 
 & & & (-8.04) &(-0.90) & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{enumerate} [ $^1$ ]
%\item [\text{Note: }]
\item Footnote1
\item Footnote2

\end{enumerate}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much David. But the real titles behind "Taxation1", "Taxation2" etc are each 4-5 words long. If I put in the actual titles, only the first 2 columns of the table are visible on the page. Could you please suggest how I can modify this?

Comment: use multiline titles, eg replace `\textit{#1}` by `\textit{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}`  then you can use `\hd{my\\long\\title\\here}`

Comment: Thank you for the quick help David! I'm able to create the table exactly the way I want. I have a wide variety of tables, let me go and do the same with all of them. Thanks again!